# c pointer error , get current time

Tags: c, pointers, time

I'm a beginner in C , can you explain for me please how to fix this error.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *getDate()
{
    SYSTEMTIME str_t;
    GetSystemTime(&str_t);

    int tab[3];
    tab[0]=str_t.wDay;
    tab[1]=str_t.wMonth;
    tab[2]=str_t.wYear;

    return tab;
}

struct node
{
    int *date= getDate();
};

void main()
{
    struct node n1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    int *tab = n1->date;
    printf("Jour : %d , Mois : %d , Anne : %d",tab[0],tab[1],tab[2]);
}
```

*error is : return from incompatible pointer type.*

ps : i tried return &tab in return of getDate same error

thank you.

Comment: Amar, I suspect you are using [tag:c++], is this 100% surely [tag:c] code? because this `struct node {int *date = getDate();};` is invalid and `struct node n1 = (struct node *) malloc()` is too, also note that the left hand side of the assignment has a different type in the `malloc()`.

Comment: also `node->date` should be `n1->date`

Comment: Also you are never calling the constructor for `node` so your `date` field is never being set

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby The constructor????? What? If this is [tag:c] then there is no such thing. If lt's c++, then calling the constructur is why `malloc()` shouldn't be used but `new` instead.

Comment: @iharob OP has a function call in his `struct` declaration, you yourself said you assume this is c++?

Comment: yes , i'm using C ... i'm new in C , can you help me and tell me how to fix it, i changed node->date to n1->node , still don't work

Comment: @iharob Right, I'm not saying he needs to keep the malloc, obviously he does not, I'm pointing out that without constructing the `struct` (i.e. using `new`) his date field is not being set

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby - there is no `new` in `c` / and the OP says that this is 'c'

Comment: @KevinDTimm I understand there is no `new` in `c`, the way OP declared his `struct` provided the assumption that he was using `c++`

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby It would be invalid in [tag:c++] too, it looks more like java in fact. I was trying to understand why the code is the way it is.

Comment: @AmarBessalah Why are you using `GetSystemTime()`? Why don't you use *standard* functions?

Comment: i searched in google how to get system Time and found this

Comment: @iharob its not "invalid", it just doesn't work how OP thinks it does. If `getDate()` returned the address of a global `int`, then it would work just fine

Answer (score 2):

getDate allocate tab[3] in top of stack,
And this variable is no longer reachable after getDate returns.

Since getDate stack is destroyed by returning and tab[3] has the life of getDate scope and is destroyed by the same way.

If you make tab[3] static, tab[3] will have the lifetime of your programe.

Try this out :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *getDate()
{
    SYSTEMTIME str_t;
    static int tab[3];

    GetSystemTime(&str_t);

    tab[0] = str_t.wDay;
    tab[1] = str_t.wMonth;
    tab[2] = str_t.wYear;

    return tab;
}

struct node{
    int *date;
};

void main()
{
    struct node* n1 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int *tab;
    n1->date = getDate();

    tab = n1->date;
    printf("Jour : %d , Mois : %d , Anne : %d",tab[0],tab[1],tab[2]);

}
```

(In C, struct node isn't a constructor, but just a data structure).

Comment: I edited your answer, change `struct node n1` to `struct node* n1` and change `node` to `n1` in `main()` after the `malloc` call

Comment: Also in C you need to declare`int* tab` after `struct node* n1`

Comment: I thought that this depend on compiler version you uses.

Comment: with ANSI C (C90) you're limited to declaring variables after an opening `{` as far as I understand

Comment: @LewisAnesa I believe with C99 the limitation on variable declaration does not exist

Comment: Yes, we're okay on that.